# Why r shows an error when using dplyr and ifelse together?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am trying to use the "ifelse" function in R grouping but it doesn't work. 
My data is something like this:

```
Breed Animal
NOR    1  
NOR    1
SWE    1
HOL    2
NOR    2
NOR    3
NOR    3
```

So I want to create a new variable, called "comp" for composition in which if the breed for the animal is always NOR, it is purebred, if not, it is admixed.
The data.frame is called NOR and the code I used is:

```
NOR %>%
group_by (animal) %>%%
mutate(comp= ifelse(NOR$breed == "NOR", "purebred","admixed")
```

But then I have this error: Error: Column 'comp' must be length 28 (the group size) or one, not 1104.

The output that I  need is:

```
Breed Animal comp  
NOR     1     admixed
NOR     1     admixed
SWE     1     admixed
HOL     2     admixed
NOR     2     admixed
NOR     3     purebred
NOR     3     pubebred
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Remove the `NOR$`. Using `NOR$breed` gives you the full column, but you're attempting to do an operation by group so you need the subset of the column for that group, which `dplyr` gives automatically with just `breed`. (This is why the error is telling you your vector is larger than the group size)

Comment: In addition to what @IceCreamToucan said, whenever you chain something using using ```%>%``` you won't have to use that dataframe name later if you're just referencing a column in it

Comment: You also have a typo: `%>%%` should be `%>%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, we can use `if/else` as the input is a single TRUE/FALSE value

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(Animal) %>% 
     mutate(comp = if(all(Breed == "NOR")) "purebred" else "admixed")
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   Animal [3]
#  Breed Animal comp    
#  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>   
#1 NOR        1 admixed 
#2 NOR        1 admixed 
#3 SWE        1 admixed 
#4 HOL        2 admixed 
#5 NOR        2 admixed 
#6 NOR        3 purebred
#7 NOR        3 purebred
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Breed = c("NOR", "NOR", "SWE", "HOL", "NOR", "NOR", 
"NOR"), Animal = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -7L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It's true! Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 2):

Example data.

```
df <- tibble(
   "Breed" = c(rep("NOR", 2), "SWE", "HOL", rep("NOR", 3)),
   "Animal" = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2), rep(3, 2))
)

> df
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  Breed Animal
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 NOR        1
2 NOR        1
3 SWE        1
4 HOL        2
5 NOR        2
6 NOR        3
7 NOR        3
```

Instead of 'NOR$breed', you want to have just 'Breed'. You also want to wrap the condition in 'all'.

```
df %>%
   group_by(Animal) %>%
   mutate(comp = ifelse(all(Breed == "NOR"), "purebred", "admixed"))

# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   Animal [3]
  Breed Animal comp    
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>   
1 NOR        1 admixed 
2 NOR        1 admixed 
3 SWE        1 admixed 
4 HOL        2 admixed 
5 NOR        2 admixed 
6 NOR        3 purebred
7 NOR        3 purebred
```

Comment: Yes, but actually, the results it is giving is not exactly what I need. Because I am not sure if it is grouping well since for the same animal all the rows in comp should be equals. For example, animals 1 and 2 should be admixed in all their rows....

Comment: Edited answer. All you need to do is wrap the condition in 'all'.